# OpenGL Python Maya API drawing without MPxLocator plugin

Tags: python, api, opengl, maya

I'm trying to do something simple like this in the maya python api:

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as OpenMayaUI
import maya.OpenMayaRender as OpenMayaRender

#Get active camera.
view = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()

glFT = OpenMayaRender.MHardwareRenderer.theRenderer().glFunctionTable()

view.beginGL()

glFT.glBegin(OpenMayaRender.MGL_LINES)
glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
glFT.glEnd()

view.endGL()
```

I just want to draw a line in maya without having to build a MPxLocator or what have you to display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found I needed to actually add callback to the view to get it to draw:

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as OpenMayaUI
import maya.OpenMayaRender as OpenMayaRender
import maya.cmds as cmds


def setCamera(*args):
    view = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()

    # Get a renderer, then a function table
    glRenderer = OpenMayaRender.MHardwareRenderer.theRenderer()
    glFT = glRenderer.glFunctionTable()

    view.beginGL()

    glFT.glPushAttrib(OpenMayaRender.MGL_LINE_BIT)
    glFT.glLineWidth(5.0)

    glFT.glBegin(OpenMayaRender.MGL_LINES)

    glFT.glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glFT.glVertex3f(3.0, 0.0, 0.0)

    glFT.glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 3.0, 0.0)

    glFT.glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glFT.glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 3.0)

    glFT.glEnd()

    glFT.glPopAttrib()

    view.endGL()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
    callBack = OpenMayaUI.MUiMessage.add3dViewPostRenderMsgCallback(
        panel, setCamera)

    view = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()
    view.refresh(True, True)
```

And then to remove the callback:

```
OpenMayaUI.MUiMessage.removeCallback(callBack)
view = OpenMayaUI.M3dView.active3dView()
view.refresh(True, True)
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: It is interesting. How/Where are you applying it. What purpose. If I may know?

Comment: I was using for testing. I considered using it as well to draw simple gl things like matrices and normals, but never decided to utilize it. Here's where I got the interest from.  https://vimeo.com/78681528

Comment: For future readers - this works great in the legacy maya viewport -- but if you're using 'Viewport 2.0' or later  it does not draw